# OWIN Authentication, Authorization code migration from .net framework to .net 6 (Token based Authentication)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, owin, .net-6.0, openiddict

We have implemented OWIN Authorization to our Web Api's in .Net framework project. Now we are migrating this to .Net6. It seems in .net6/.net core owin authentication is not supported.

I don't find any documentation around this.

It seems Microsoft.Owin.OwinMiddleware is not exits in .net core.Also I don't find any Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenProvider corresponding nuget packages in .net core.

How can we use OWIN Authorization in .Net core(.net6)? If it is not supported what is alternative to this in .net core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET Core using a new authentication middleware which could work like OWIN.

So you could directly using this middleware instead of using owin inside the asp.net core.

For example, if you want to include the MSFT, Goolge, facebook or else, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: If I want to add my own custom provider how can we achieve that in .net core. I find openiddict is replacement/new oauth provider for .net core. It would really helpful if you can guide on how can I migrate my current owin authenction using openiddict or any other oauth provider in .net core